# UIPageViewControllerDataSource methods not invoked for edge cases

Tags: ios, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I'm writing an app where I'd like to use left-swipe and right-swipe gestures to move from one `UIViewController` to the next by using the routines described in `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`.

I started off with [How to Use UIPageViewController in Swift (Tutorial)](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial) . It's outdated, but I've tweaked it enough to get it up and running on iOS 9.3 through 10.2.

It works fine for most cases but not for edge cases in both the figurative and literal sense.  Specifically, I'd like to be able to swipe right on the rightmost page and have the leftmost page appear -- not unlike the pages on the bottom of Apple's "Stocks" app where the user can swipe right from stats to graph, again to headlines and cycle back to stats with one more right-swipe gesture.

The problem is, when I swipe left in my app from pages [1] through [N-1,  my `pageViewController(:viewControllerBefore)` function is getting called but not on page [0].  Swipe right gestures will invoke by `pageViewController(:viewControllerAfter)` for pages [0] through [N-2] but not for page [N-1].

Comment: It sounds like a puzzling problem.  How can we help?

Comment: I'm not quite sure yet -- at this point I'm just wondering if this sounds familiar to anyone.  Maybe there's something in some related class that I need to set or override to prevent a test that might be preventing my `pageViewController(:viewControllerBefore)` from getting called when I'd like to move from [0] to [N-1].  I haven't found anything in their documentation or here thus far.

Comment: Not familiar sounding to me.  I think the way forward is to inspect code.  Do you build your page vcs as you need them, or are they kept allocated in an array?